# Custom Dropdown List for Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

In the picture above (tablet landscape mode), any way I can minimize the Dropdown width of a Spinner? Or create a Custom Dropdown perhaps? Thanks.

Edit:
I'm just using this android's own layout.
spinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

XML Added:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Font Size"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your code snippet. so that we can help you based on it

Comment: I mean add the xml which contains the spinner item defined

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, your linear layout's width is set to fill parent. Try replacing it to wrap content. It might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for custom spinner style..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="8pt"        
         android:textColor="#000000"         
         android:gravity="center"/>
     <TextView
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
         android:id="@+id/subText"              
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this for the spinner in your main layout...

```
 <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/spinner1"
             android:layout_width="250dp"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 
             android:prompt="@string/prompt"/>
```